# ASP.NET Entity Framework 7 config.json ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have a problem at creating my database in a MVC 6 ASP.NET Application. When I'm trying to add migrations in the cmd by executing "dnx ef migrations add initial", I receive the exception 
"The value is not allowed to be NULL. Parametername: connectionString" (it's translated from German, so in english the literal translation could be different)

I searched through the whole web, but I couldn't find anything that helped.

This is my config.json:

```
  {
    "AppSettings": {
      "SiteTitle": "Chronicus"
    },
    "Data": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Chronicus;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
```

This is my Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Chronicus.models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


namespace Chronicus
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {

            // Setup configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ChronicusContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            /*
            // auto generated code
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });

            */
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

This is my project.json

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands":  "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know, how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a typo in your first block, this does not appear to be valid json as there is an opening `{` missing.

```
  {
    "AppSettings": {
      "SiteTitle": "Chronicus"
    },
    "Data": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Chronicus;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

Should be

```
  {
    "AppSettings": {
      "SiteTitle": "Chronicus"
    },
    "Data": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Chronicus;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
```

Notice the two opening `{`

**Edit**

It appears like your config.json may not be correct. Please format your config using the following example

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "SiteTitle": "WebApplication2",
    },
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-WebApplication1-414415dc-a108-49f3-a5e3-fdc4cf24ef96;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was just wrong copied so it will not solve the problem, but still thank you for looking at my problem.

Comment: Now you have too many `{` and `}`. Remove the first and last ones.

Comment: @davidrue Can you verify each of the `.json` configuration files are valid? If you need, you can easily find JSON validators online .

Comment: Okay, seemed like it wasn't valid, i removed the first and last one and now there is the exception: "The value is not allowed to be NULL. Parametername: connectionString" (it's translated from German, so in english the literal translation could be different)

Comment: Change ConnectionString to connectionString in your config.json

Comment: @Seany84 Changing to "connectionString" didn't solve the problem

Comment: @Seany84 Thank you! That was the solution!

Comment: @davidrue No problem. Don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its the **wrong json**, you set the configuration to take the property here:

```
Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])
```

Your json need to be this:

```
{   
"AppSettings": {
      "SiteTitle": "Chronicus"   
},   
"Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
          "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Chronicus;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
                             }   
        } 
}
```

**Other problem** can be the method to take the config,
Try this:

```
Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");
```

instead of this:

```
Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
```

For more informations, try [this link.](http://wildermuth.com/2015/3/17/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_3_-_EF7)